# I get (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'adding ) when trying to add to a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert a card into the player list. Here's my code and the error I get:

```
def deal_card():
    """Returns a random card from the deck."""
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card = random.choice(cards)
    return card

player = deal_card()
print(type(player))
player.insert(deal_card())
print(player)
```

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

I've tried `.append` and `.add`. Why does my code throw this error and how do I fix it?

What I want is [ 2, 3, 5]

Comment: If `player = deal_card()` then `player` is a number. You cannot insert a number into a number because number is not a collection. Did you mean to instantiate `player` as a list of numbers?

Comment: So what does `print(type(player))` output? Is `player` a list? According to this code, it's an integer.

Comment: print(type(player) gives me and "int"

Answer (score 0):

player = [player] + [deal_card()]
print(player)

gives me[3, 5]

thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this error means you are trying to call `insert()` method which owned by list data type, while the data type you are trying to use is an Integer. In your `deal_card` function,

```
def deal_card():
    """Returns a random card from the deck."""
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card = random.choice(cards)
    return card
```

`card = random.choice(cards)` will give choose a random value from your `cards` list, in which will return a whatever type that is chosen in `cards` list, in your cases is an Integer type.

note that insert() must have 2 parameters to be passed for further information, you can read [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert)

if you want to make a list of the chosen random cards i would recommend to use `append()` and you can try to use a different attribute maybe called `card` for passing the data, or just directly append the `deal_card` function since its return a value, here's an example:

```
# to use append you should already have a list whether its empty or not
player = []
card = deal_card()
# can also use player.append(deal_card()), in that case you won't need the card variable
player.append(card)
```